# Getting symbols instead of int

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm getting symbols instead of int when I ask the user to enter the `rown` & `coln` with the `readint` and `writestring` afterward.  How can I get the int entered to show up?

```
.686
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.STACK
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.Data
txt1 byte "ENTER NUM OF ROWS:",0dh,0ah,0
txt2 byte "ENTER NUM OF COLUMNS:",0dh,0ah,0
txt3 byte "ENTER AN ARRAY OF"

rown byte 0,"x"                             ;rows number
coln byte 0,":",0dh,0ah,0                   ;columns number


.CODE
main PROC
mov edx,offset txt1
call writestring                            ;asks the user to enter the rows number
call readint
mov rown,al
mov edx,offset txt2
call writestring
call readint                                ;asks the user to enter the columns number
mov coln,al

mov edx, offset txt3
call writestring  ;;;;; here is the problem !!!!!
call waitmsg
       exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What processor / instruction set is this for?

Comment: You should probably identify the platform, and the o/s.  The chances of anyone being able to answer the question are slim; we don't have the code for `readint`, etc.

Comment: You'll probably need to convert the number to text first or use a `writeint` function if such a function exists for each of the numbers.

Comment: @djacobson Looks like x86 to me

Answer (score 2):

I'm juts guessing since the important part of the code is missing.
Since `readInt` read and returns a number, you should probably re-convert it to a string before writing.
Just to be sure, try to enter `97` (decimal) as the number of columns and rows. If I am not mistaken, the output message will be `"ENTER AN ARRAY OF axa:"`

Answer (score 0):

Irvine's [`ReadInt`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadint.htm) converts the inputted number into the CPU internal format "DWORD". To write it as ASCII (`WriteString`) it must be converted. Since in the posted program is reserved only one byte for each number and only stored `AL`, I assume that only the range 0..9 has to be converted. Hence, just one number has to be converted to one ASCII character. A conversion table looks like this:

```
CPU -> ASCII
 0  ->  48
 1  ->  49
 2  ->  50
 3  ->  51
 4  ->  52
 5  ->  53
 6  ->  54
 7  ->  55
 8  ->  56
 9  ->  57
```

Tl;dr: Just add 48 to `AL`:

```
;.686                                       ; Included in Irvine32.inc
;.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL                       ; Included in Irvine32.inc
;.STACK                                     ; Not needed for .MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
    txt1 byte "ENTER NUM OF ROWS:",0dh,0ah,0
    txt2 byte "ENTER NUM OF COLUMNS:",0dh,0ah,0
    txt3 byte "ENTER AN ARRAY OF "

    rown byte 0,"x"                             ;rows number
    coln byte 0,":",0dh,0ah,0                   ;columns number

.CODE
main PROC
    mov edx,offset txt1
    call WriteString                        ;asks the user to enter the rows number
    call ReadInt
    add al, 48
    mov rown, al
    mov edx, offset txt2
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt                            ;asks the user to enter the columns number
    add al, 48
    mov coln, al
    mov edx, offset txt3
    call WriteString
    call WaitMsg
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Some caveats:

1) Irvine's [`ReadInt`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadint.htm) "reads a 32-bit signed decimal integer". Thus, the number in `EAX` can be out of the range 0..9 and in `AL` is anything else than a valid number. To convert the whole value in `EAX` take a look [`here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820360/assembly-write-number-to-file/34462084#34462084).

2) At `rown` and `coln` are now ASCII characters. They eventually have to be converted to integer before further processing.

3) A conversion of a DWORD that would lead to two decimal digits or more is a little bit more complicated.The single digits must be isolated by repeatedly divide by 10 and store the remainder.